# netpbm fails to install when installing with Homebrew on OS X

Tags: ros, macos, homebrew, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When building packages that depend on netpbm on OS X using Homebrew, netpbm fails to install due to a libpng version mismatch.  This only seems to occur on Xcode 4.2.1 but could affect others.

Here is the error output:

https://gist.github.com/1456449

I have opened a ticket here:

https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/9079

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12308/netpbm-fails-to-install-when-installing-with-homebrew-on-os-x/) by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17335 on 2011-12-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a work around until it is fixed upstream within Homebrew:

`brew install netpbm --HEAD`

And then resume using normal ROS commands.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2011-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2